# How to read and process a file with "do notation"?

Tags: haskell

For instance I want to read a file containing only integers and do something with these integers like in the function:

```
getIntFromFile :: () -> Int
getIntFromFile _ = do
                     h <- openFile "/tmp/file" ReadMode
                     str <- hGetLine h
                     let x = read str :: Int

                     str <- hGetLine h
                     let y = read str :: Int

                     hClose h
                     x + y
```

When I load the file containing this function into ghci I get the output

```
Prelude System.IO> :l graphBat.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Plugins.GraphBat ( graphBat.hs, interpreted )

graphBat.hs:77:22:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO b0’ with ‘() -> Int’
    Expected type: IO Handle -> (Handle -> IO b0) -> () -> Int
      Actual type: IO Handle -> (Handle -> IO b0) -> IO b0
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: h <- openFile "/tmp/file" ReadMode
    In the expression:
      do { h <- openFile "/tmp/file" ReadMode;
           str <- hGetLine h;
           let x = ...;
           str <- hGetLine h;
           .... }
    In an equation for ‘getIntFromFile’:
        getIntFromFile
          = do { h <- openFile "/tmp/file" ReadMode;
                 str <- hGetLine h;
                 let x = ...;
                 .... }

graphBat.hs:85:22:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b0’ with actual type ‘Int’
    In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘x’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: x + y

graphBat.hs:85:26:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b0’ with actual type ‘Int’
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘y’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: x + y
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What do I do wrong? How should I write a typical function which reads a file, processes this file and returns the result of this processing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do IO, you must work within the IO monad:

```
getIntFromFile :: () -> IO Int   -- Added IO here
getIntFromFile _ = do
                     h <- openFile "/tmp/file" ReadMode
                     str <- hGetLine h
                     let x = read str :: Int

                     str <- hGetLine h
                     let y = read str :: Int

                     hClose h
                     return (x + y)   -- Added return
```

You can also remove the `()` parameter and start with:

```
getIntFromFile :: IO Int   -- Added IO here
getIntFromFile = do
             ...
```

In fact, using `() -> ...` is an antipattern in Haskell.